# How to fix CREATE SUBSCRIPTION command error in PostgreSQL Aurora Serverless v2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-replication, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL database replica using the CREATE SUBSCRIPTION command. The command is taking a very long time (20 minute & i terminate session) to run and I don't know why. I have checked the common reasons why this command might take a long time to run, but I can't seem to find the problem. Can you help me?

Here are some additional details that you might want to include in your question:

The version of PostgreSQL that you are using: 13.10
Your database configuration: sample
The exact command that you are running: `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION testsub CONNECTION  'host=rdos.cluster-cndftefp0ds.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=sample user=x password=x'  PUBLICATION testpub;`

Aurora Parameter:

1. rds.logical_replication = 1
2. max_replication_slots  =20
3. max_wal_senders = 10
4. max_logical_replication_workers = 4
5. max_worker_processes = GREATEST(${DBInstanceVCPU*2},8)

My table has 5 record with a column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4jna.png)

I tried to create a PostgreSQL database replica using the CREATE SUBSCRIPTION command. I expected the command to run quickly, but it took a very long time. I checked the common reasons why this command might take a long time to run, but I couldn't seem to find the problem.

Here are some things that I tried:

I checked the version of PostgreSQL that I was using. I was using the latest version, so that wasn't the problem.
I checked my database configuration. Everything seemed to be in order, so that wasn't the problem either.
I checked the exact command that I was running. I made sure that I was using the correct syntax, but that wasn't the problem either.
I checked the exact error that I was getting. The error message didn't give me any clues as to what the problem was.
I'm still not sure what the problem is, but I'm hoping that someone on Stack Overflow will be able to help me figure it out.

I'm also hoping that someone on Stack Overflow will be able to suggest some ways to improve the performance of the CREATE SUBSCRIPTION command. I think that it would be very helpful if the command could run more quickly.

Comment: "I have checked the common reasons why this command might take a long time to run, but I can't seem to find the problem"  We don't know what you checked, because we don't know what you (or ChatGPT) think the common reasons are.  Tell us what you did.